# How do I set color range in Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've created a `ColumnChart` and it has two bars. How can I set different colours on these two bars?

I'm currently only able to set one color for both bars,

This is part of the code I use:

```
var d = [['', ''], ['Bar 1', 100], ['Bar 2', 300]]; 
data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);    

var option = {
  title: 'Betalingsoppf&oslash;lging',
  width: '300',
  height: '250',
  min:  '0',
  legend: 'none',
  colors: ['#b2cedc', '#7b7b7b','#e2e2e2', '#747c1f']
}

wrap.setOptions(option);
wrap.draw(data);
```

The intention with `colors: ['#b2cedc', '#7b7b7b','#b2cedc', '#7b7b7b']` is to set start-end colour for bar1 and bar 2. But all i does, is to use the first color defined.

And is there a way to chagne the background color through options?

**Test code for Visualization tool**

Cut and paste this into [Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart).

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var raw_data = [['Austria', 150000, 225000]];

  var years = [2003, 2004];

  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
    data.addColumn('number', raw_data[i][0]);    
  }

  data.addRows(years.length);

  for (var j = 0; j < years.length; ++j) {    
    data.setValue(j, 0, years[j].toString());    
  }
  for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 1; j  < raw_data[i].length; ++j) {
      data.setValue(j-1, i+1, raw_data[i][j]);    
    }
  }

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Color testing",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"},
            colors: ['#dedb70', '#747c1f','yellow', 'red'],
            min: '0',
            legend: 'none'
           }
      );
}
```

Comment: Do you need specific colors, or just all distinct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the colors can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you are only entering one entry, Austria, with multiple data points. `colors` sets the color for each entry, not each entry's data point. The chart does not have an option I can find for multiple data point colors.

To see what I mean change:

`var raw_data = [['Austria', 150000, 225000]];`

to

`var raw_data = [['Austria', 150000, 225000],['Japan',100000,200000]];`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the color codes, it will repeat the set you give it.

```
colors: ['#b2cedc', '#7b7b7b']
```

You can also just let it use the default, which will give a distinct color set, if you're not picky about the colors.

Background color is changed through `backgroundColor`. It takes a string like 'red' or '#b2cedc'

There's a nice [tool](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart) you can play with to test your code on the fly. The above color code inserted in after `width:600, height:400,` colors in every other line like it should.

[This documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart.html) might also be helpful.

Comment: Using `colors: ['#b2cedc', '#7b7b7b']` will set the same color for all bars. I need different colour for differenet bars.

Comment: If no color is defined, it uses default color blue. If I use `colors: ['#b2cedc', '#7b7b7b']`, it only useses `#b2cedc`.

Comment: Do you have more complete code? What you've posted doesn't run in the simulator. It sounds like your problem is that it only thinks there's one bar instead of two. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#google.visualization.arraytodatatable) for `arrayToDatatable` shows it has a lot of limitations. Try using an alternate way to build your chart?

Comment: No, this is not all the code, just parts of it. The code runs fine. I only need to set thecolors. I've added Code Playgournd test code above. Uses that and see if you can chagne the bar colors.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful code: i found it here.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-visualization-api/jCVmevbBT4Q

```
   function drawVisualization() {
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
       data.addRows(4);
       data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
       data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
       data.setValue(0, 2, 400);
       data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
       data.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
       data.setValue(1, 2, 460);
       data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
       data.setValue(2, 1, 660);
       data.setValue(2, 2, 1120);
       data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
       data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
       data.setValue(3, 2, 540);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, { width: 640, height: 480, title: 'Company Performance',
                     vAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red'} },
                     legend: 'none', colors: ['#cc00cc', '#ccffcc']
                    });

    changeColors();

    }

    function changeColors() {
     var chartArea = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')           [0].contentDocument.getElementById('chartArea');
      var nodes = chartArea.getElementsByTagName('rect');

       // finding all <rect> elements with #cc00cc fill color and replacing them with      'blue','red','green','blue'
       for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('fill') && node.getAttribute('fill') == '#cc00cc') {
      switch (i % 4) {
        case 0:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
          break;
        case 1:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
          break;
        case 2:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'green');
          break;
        case 3:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  // finding all <rect> elements with #ccffcc fill color and replacing them with 'blue','red','green','blue'
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('fill') && node.getAttribute('fill') == '#ccffcc') {
      switch (i % 4) {
        case 0:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
          break;
        case 1:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
          break;
        case 2:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'green');
          break;
        case 3:
          node.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
          break;
         }
       }
      }
    }
```